# ndt_gpu crashes with Eigen Error

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, cuda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Environment:**

- Ubuntu 18.04.3
- Kernel 4.15.0-58-generic
- CUDA 10.0
- CuDNN 7.6.2
- Eigen 3.3.7

When I build Autoware 1.12.0 from source with the `AUTOWARE_COMPILE_WITH_CUDA=1` environmental variable set, I get the following crash of `ndt_gpu` when running with any method:

```
ndt_matching: /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:109: Eigen::internal::plain_array<T, Size, MatrixOrArrayOptions, 16>::plain_array() [with T = float; int Size = 16; int MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0]: Assertion `(internal::UIntPtr(eigen_unaligned_array_assert_workaround_gcc47(array)) & (15)) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****"' failed.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330713/ndt_gpu-crashes-with-eigen-error/) by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1766 on 2019-08-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on 2019-08-14**:
I got the same error, and it seemed to occur only in Debug build.
I decided to use Release build tentatively, but I feel it should be fixed.

Did you build Autoware in the Debug mode?

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2019-08-15**:
Yes, I did. Thanks for checking into this. I'll see if I can figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Though this is no a fundamental solution,  I found adding `add_definitions(-DEIGEN_DISABLE_UNALIGNED_ARRAY_ASSERT)` to  `autoware/core_perception/ndt_cpu/CMakeLists.txt` can ignore this error.

(Note: not `ndt_gpu` but `ndt_cpu`)

I'll send an MR for this as a temporary measure.

---

Originally posted by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) with karma: 307 on 2019-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on 2019-10-29**:
I'm adding notes for the future reference.

I tried many solutions written in http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html, but I couldn't solve this problem completely.

I found this minimal code can reproduce the error. (Instantiating only either one didn't cause it, but I'm not sure the reason.)

```
// core_perception/lidar_localizer/ndt_matching.cpp
#include <ndt_cpu/NormalDistributionsTransform.h>
#include <ndt_gpu/NormalDistributionsTransform.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Instantiate these classes(or inherited classes) at the same time
  cpu::Registration<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ> tmp_cpu;
  gpu::GRegistration tmp_gpu;

  return 0;
}
```

Also, when I tested this code without ROS, the error didn't occur.
Therefore, I guess Autoware's ROS usage is causing some conflicts.
Probably similar to this problem.
https://github.com/dqrobotics/cpp/issues/22

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2019-10-30**:
@kenji-miyake Thank you so much for looking into this and providing the MR with the fix!

**Comment by [Badal](https://answers.ros.org/users/82298/badal/) on 2023-04-14**:
Thank you so much , it fix my problem related to ORB_SLAM3 as well .